# Can we redirect from login page(non content page) to master page via login button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, master-pages

There should be login button and cancel button

Page should get to redirect to master page when submit button is clicked

Comment: Insert some code. We are not robots....

Comment: With all respects but do you honestly think that the community can give any helpful advice with so little information given? Please add a meaningful description of the issue, code samples, what you've tried so far etc...

Comment: i just want to know is it possible to do that?? because my login page is a normal web form page and i want to redirect it to a master page via login button and once i am clicking login button i am getting HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.

Comment: Do you have a content page for your master page?. @RituJha

Answer (score 0):

try using this to redirect to the default page

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Reponse.Redirec("~");
}
```

Comment: i tried but getting error:  HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided very little information for someone to give an accurate answer.

- I am assuming that the name of the master page to which you want to
  redirect on successful login is *Master.aspx* and furthermore
  this page is in root directory of your ASP.Net web app.
- Also, I am assuming that you have a *Login* method returning a bool value in your code-behind of login page that contains the logic for login process of a user and which accepts two parameters of user name and password.

Then, you need to have code like below. You'll need to adapt this code to your requirements by replacing the user name text box id, password textbox id, login method name and master page name.

```
protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //txtUserName is textbox for inputting user name on login page
    //txtPwd is textbox for inputting password on login page
    bool isValidLogin = Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPwd.Text);
    if (isValidLogin) {
              Response.Redirect("~/Master.aspx");
    }
}
```